# Removing placeholder text on focus

Tags: forms, input-fields, placeholder, input-focus

- Chrome, Safari, and Firefox 15+ remove the placeholder text after the users first key press in the text input field.
- Opera, IE, and Firefox 14 and below remove placeholder text immediately after focusing the text input.

**Which approach is better for users and why?**

*Test placeholder in your browser on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webvitaly/bGrQ4/2/embedded/result/).*

**Update: [Placeholders in Form Fields Are Harmful](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/)**

Comment: Here is one of many workarounds to make all browsers behave like Chrome on this regard: https://github.com/ripper234/input-placeholder.

Comment: Sure is a lot of speculation in this thread. Can someone post an answer with user research applied?

Comment: Curious if there is an implication for screen readers.

Comment: Good question, but +1 For the update too!

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Interestingly the [w3 Spec for placeholder](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-placeholder) allows for either behavior:

> User agents should present this hint to the user, after having stripped line breaks from it, when the element's value is the empty string and/or the control is not focused (e.g. by displaying it inside a blank unfocused control and hiding it otherwise).

But, functionally speaking, there's little reason to clear it before the user starts typing. Users tabbing through your form might never see it because they'll tab into the field before seeing the placeholder text. Mouse users might not have finished reading the placeholder text before they click.

If your field is complex enough to require a placeholder, it probably requires some thought; what better time to think "what should I input?" than when you're focused on the field? Why take away that hint from users focused in the field but confused as to what to type?

Comment: +1 I would go so far as to say it IS better to remove the text after they start typing, for the reasons you stated.

Comment: I updated the code, I think this would be more clear for user which input is focused - http://jsfiddle.net/webvitaly/bGrQ4/2/embedded/result/

Now if user focus the input, the placeholder text become more lighter to indicate that it is only the hint and exactly this input is focused. 
This code works in chrome only, because other browsers remove placeholder on focus.

Comment: @webvitaly interesting touch, though I'd want to make it apparent that the placeholder isn't a default/value, which is why I think they stray on the faded-out side instead of looking like normal text. I've also seen italics used to indicate *this text isn't real*

Comment: @BenBrocka If we are duplicating label text in placeholder text (very often) and sometimes user could not understand that placeholder text is the hint text so there is no need to use the placeholder at all and it is more clear for user to leave blank input and simple label.
Hm, funny, I returned to the point from where the web-forms were started many years ago :)

Comment: showing the placeholder when the field is focused is also interesting for the case where the field is also autofocus. if the placeholder disappear on focus, the user wouldn't have a chance to see it

Comment: My concern with placeholder text is that users may get confused that they cannot select and delete the text that is in the field. Are there any studies regarding placeholder text?

Comment: firefox is moving toward keeping the placeholder while empty and focused : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=673873

Comment: Maybe an experiment like this can help users tell that they're supposed to type over the placeholder text?

http://jsfiddle.net/JeZF4/3/

Comment: @CodeJunkie I like the "Move over and fade" on focus; I've seen the "fade" before and find it useful, but I like the move over too, it sort of gets out of the cursor's way.

Comment: +1 "what better time to think "what should I input?" than when you're focused on the field?"

Comment: Firefox 15 now removes placeholder on typing. 14 and before used to remove on focus.

Answer (score 44):

I would side with having the placeholder text show as long as possible without getting in the way.

The way it is done in Chrome is better, in my opinion.

I've found ways to get around this on all browsers, however.

What I've done in the past is remove the placeholder text on focus, but also re-displayed that text by making the label--which is almost always a duplicate of the placeholder and, if not, at least as or more descriptive--show up as a tab.

For example, here is part of my form with no fields in focus:

[image]

And here is part of my form with a field in focus:

[image]

This way, a user is never confused as to what exactly they've typed into a field. They can check back by re-focusing on the field.

Comment: Another variant of this I've seen is for field text to 'fly' out of the way to the left or right. I'll try and find an example to link to.

Comment: Though in an example like this, why not just have labels above the fields? I understand that sometimes moving labels inside the fields is needed for space, but I also find that it's done a lot of the time even when space is plentiful.

Comment: In this case, the designer was going for as clean a look as possible, so he opted for showing just placeholder text rather than the label above, but we wanted to ensure that once the field was focused, there would be no confusion.

Comment: "clean look" shouldn't trump usability, though. ;) (Granted, I don't know the full context of this example)

Comment: Right, but it's not any less useable this way, right?

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye I'm not advocating the replacement of labels by placeholders, and this mechanism isn't quite perfect, but maybe you're thinking of this one at [CSS Plus](http://css-plus.com/examples/2011/09/userfriendly-input-placeholder)

Comment: @magzalez not on modern browsers; but the more fancy stuff you do the more likely you are to have to either code kludge arounds or suffer usability regressions in legacy browsers.  As always TANSTAAFL.

Comment: @magzalez moving the labels above on focus is perhaps not less usable. So that's OK. That said, it seems like an unnecessarily complex interaction that pretty much achieves the same end-result: a label above the field. You also lose the label after blurring, so that could be construed as a bit of a usability hit (especially on a large form)

Comment: @RogerAttrill - yes, that's the pattern I've seen. Whether it's the best solution, though, I'm still not sure. I'd have to think about it.

Comment: I'm not sure I like the placeholder text being so high contrast; seems easy to confuse with normal text like a default value for that input, no? I do really like the "label" it forms when you're typing though.

Comment: @BenBrocka, I agree with you about the text color. It should be lighter to indicate it is not the final text.

Answer (score 14):

**Removing it when you start typing is better**

Depending on how the focus was moved to the input field, the user may not necessarily see the placeholder text before it quickly disappears.

Yes you might read it before you *manually* click in the field but perhaps not if you happened to *tab* into the field from the previous input.

There's also the possibility that the first input field gets focus by default when a page is displayed, in which case the placeholder would still be good to see.

Comment: Yes people actually tab through web forms. I do, and have seen others do the same.

Comment: It shouldn't look fixed if visually designed properly (most browsers, by default, gray out the placeholder text)>

Comment: Generally the backgound colour of inactive fields becomes grey. Grey placeholder text on a white (or otherwise "active colour") field should not indicate it's disabled.

Answer (score 9):

The [change](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=758996) to preserve placeholder text on focus in the recent Firefox 15 release confused me the first time I saw it.  I actually thought the field was disabled.  In Firefox, the default styling (text color) of placeholder vs. disabled is very similar, and unlike Chrome, there isn't a default focus highlight, so the main indication that the field is editable is the cursor which can be easy to miss.  When you can't highlight or delete the text that's in your way, your first instinct if you're unfamiliar with the UI convention is not necessarily to start typing anyway.

Although there are some good practical arguments for preserving the text on focus, there's also a lot of precedent (at least in Windows) for the opposite behavior.  One [commenter](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=758996#c7) pointed out that the search box in the Windows start menu works this way, and Firefox itself has several UI fields that clear on focus.  The Windows start menu is actually an example of a hybrid approach.  Its search box is initially focused and displays the text by default, but when the user manually focuses it, the text is cleared.  I prefer this sort of compromise from a usability standpoint.

In an HTML environment, however, clean mapping to CSS (if only for [override hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)) is also important, and there isn't a selector for auto-focus vs. user-focus.  And at this point, all the browser vendors seem to be in rare agreement, so it's a bit late to be complaining.  Perhaps a simpler compromise in Firefox would have been to add a default focus style for placeholder text that faded the placeholder text more on focus so the user had stronger feedback that the field could accept their typing even though there was still placeholder text in the way.

Setting aside implementation concerns in a particular browser, my preference in general remains to hide on focus.  Although a large part of it is that it's simply what I'm accustomed to, I think there's also a fundamental aversion to trying to write in a space that's not already blank.  Experience with handwriting, typing (with a typewriter!) and computing has taught me that if there's already text there, I need to do something about it first.  I instinctively prefer a blank canvas before I start.  I can adapt to the preserve on focus pattern, but I think it's going to be difficult to feel entirely comfortable with it unless there's more of a sense of the placeholder text getting out of the way when I focus the field for editing.

Answer (score 7):

### **User scenario:**

1. User starts to fill a form of 6 fields (all filled with
   placeholders)
2. The user sees the placeholders each time  before filling the field
   and understands what needs to be filled
3. User clicks on the field and the focus makes the placeholder
   disappear.
4. Before the user might start filling the field, the user gets a
   message or mail and gets distracted for few seconds.

Now when the user comes back to fill that field which is in focus and with out placeholder. There is very high chances that the user has forgotten what he saw in the placeholder and might enter something on their assumptions.

> ***Hence, 
>    Removing it when you start typing is not good***

Answer (score 7):

Having seen someone trying to highlight some placeholder text for several minutes so that she could delete it and begin typing, I would say the delete on focus would be the most user friendly for all ranges of users.

I think the colour of the placeholder text makes a difference here as it was the same colour as the input text, maybe a light grey or something similar wouldn't have confused this particular user.

Answer (score 7):

We checked this recently in a user test and it showed clearly that the field has to be empty once a user clicked it. If the text stays in there they thought they were not able to change this field and did not even try typing.

Another thing: I remember an UX consultant from Nielsen Norman reporting that if users see an empty field they tend to write something in it. So not having placeholders might increase conversion. :-)

Comment: +1, I agree, that in most cases placeholder not needed at all, label is enough and input should be blank (without placeholder text). But there are situations when you are limited in space (like login forms) and placeholder solve this limitation.
By the way, what was the average age of tested users?

Comment: We run a test every fortnight with 5 users from 18 to no age limit, which matches our target audience. So an overall average age would not mean much. We take care to set up each test with persons between 18 and 25, 25 and 30, 40 and 50 and beyond 50. We use an external partner for recruiting them, because we can't be bothered running the entire recruitment process ourselves every 14 days. Luckily, the agency seems not to have difficulties to provide people that more or less match our age requirements.

Comment: +1, thank you for description of the user testing. Could you tell (if it is not a secret) what else confused users except placeholders? Or what other improvements you made after user testing? It is very interesting because users surprise me a lot sometimes :)

Comment: Another interesting finding was that you should NOT put mandatory check boxes just above the Submit button. Users will think this is for non-mandatory newsletter subscriptions and will neither read nor check it.

Answer (score 6):

> Which approach is better for users and why?

The better approach is the default approach. The user has chosen a browser and is used to how that browser does what it does. Don't mess with the defaults.

Comment: Whilst this is sound advice, I don't think the OP wants to override browser behaviour - just ask which is the better design. But it's certainly true that browser defaults should never be hijacked.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye hmmm depends. A great deal of proper web design is replacing browser "default" stylings. This isn't something like changing checkboxes to look like radio buttons where I would expect a "WTF" moment if suddenly placeholders behaved slightly differently.

Comment: @Ben valid argument, though note that this isn't styling. This is user interaction/behavior with a form. Forms have always had browser and OS-centric interactions...and especially true on mobile where the interaction differences can be quite drastic. *sometimes* it does make sense to reinvent the native interactions and build one's own. It's doable (and not uncommon) but I usually recommend it not be the default approach if for no other reason that it leads down a path of extra code production, testing and maintenance.

Answer (score 5):

Reading GP89 answer having seen users try to highlight or even delete placeholder text does seem to strongly suggest that removing the placeholder text on focus would be better.

Also placeholder text SHOULD be used as a minor help anyway.

The problem seems to be though people are using it as a *replacement* for labels which clearly placeholder is not. Any form which may be re/prepopulated with actual content which then of course replaces the placeholder is unusable without labels. Even a simple login form (user + password) may be prepopulated if e.g a validation message is shown after submit (maybe unknown password, and yes I know, not the recommened way to do this but best example I could think of just now). The example forms above seem to use exactly this false usage... :(

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is to avoid using placeholder text at all. There's plenty of evidence that many, many users won't understand that it is a placeholder (see the answer above for an example) and will become confused. It's a bad pattern and is completely unnecessary.

Comment: +1 I completely agree that using placeholder in most cases is the bad practice. But there are some cases when using placeholder is good solution. 

Example: login form in the topbar of the site. There are no extra space for labels and it is better to use placeholders in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome way is better, generally. It also depends on the context, however. Ther are times when a placeholder text might be so important that it is advisable to have the user manually delete the text themselves (edge-case).

Proper use of labels should help the user and prevent dependence on default values within fields.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers here deal with forms with multiple inputs. There are certainly some scenarios (using an input for a search field) where there will only be one input on the page.

In this eventuality I find it would be better to remove the placeholder on focus. The user knows what was just in there, and leaving it in place can confuse them.